# Gwenview error 'The wastebin is full. Empty it or remove items manually.'

Tags: gwenview

I have a Gwenview error: The wastebin is full. Empty it or remove items manually.

I don't know where Gwenview keeps its wastebin.  It doesn't seem to be the same one as the main wastebin as that is empty.

Could someone point me in the right direction to delete the files in the Gwenview Wastebin?

The copy I'm running is installed as a snap

Thank you for any help

Comment: OS & Release details are usually helpful (*they tell us your defaults & system stack details*), but you're right it's probably *snap* released (and related to the confinement that snaps run within)

Comment: Thank you guiverc - I'd completely forgotten about including the OS Release details

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

Comment: ...

and
gwenview 23.04.2

in
/snap/bin/gwenview

But no sign of any Trash

Comment: I've now found it via a search

.... /snap/gwenview/94/.local/share/Trash

(I wish this was visible via the application)

Comment: I don't know the app sorry (*not something I use*), but if (*or when*) you find the answer to your question, feel free to write your own answer (*which you can accept in time & thus gain rep. points*)

Comment: Thank you again guiverc. I shall do that.

Comment: My question was regarding finding the location of the Trash folder for Gwenview when installed via a snap.

Gwenview produces the error message 'The wastebin is full. Empty it or remove items manually.' but doesn't tell you where to find the Trash.

I used the command
find . -name "Trash" | sort | more

And got the result
/snap/gwenview/94/.local/share/Trash

The Trash folder contains folders 'Files' and 'Info' The contents of these folders can be deleted.

The '94' in the path is something that is changeable. It's something to do with snap.

Hope this helps other people.

Answer (score 2):

My question was regarding finding the location of the Trash folder for Gwenview when installed via a snap.

Gwenview produces the error message `The wastebin is full. Empty it or remove items manually.` but doesn't tell you where to find the Trash.

I used the command:

`find . -name "Trash" | sort | more`

And got the result:

`/snap/gwenview/94/.local/share/Trash`

Edit: `~/snap/gwenview/94/.local/share/Trash` is the correct path. (Thanks to mook765)

The Trash folder contains folders `Files` and `Info`. The contents of these folders can be deleted.

(The '94' in the path is something that is changeable. It's something to do with snap. So you'll have to search to find your Trash)

Hope this helps other people.

Comment: I think it should be `~/snap/gwenview/94/.local/share/Trash`. The folder `/snap` contains the mountpoints for the installed snaps, everything there is mounted read-only, thus you can't delete anything there.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you for the correction.